# How to proceed to next Activity after successful Login?

Tags: android

Question:
I am have successfully connected my App to my server and I get the "Successful Login" ... problem is, after that connection I can't get my Activity to pass on to the Action after the successful login. Here is my code

```
public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    Button ok,back,exit;
    TextView result;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

    }

    public void postLoginData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xxxx.com/login.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
            String username = uname.getText().toString();

            EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
            String password = pword.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("KASIRIS", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.w("KASIRIS", str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            //  startActivity(new Intent("com.sencide.OK"));
            {
                Log.w("KASIRIS", "TRUE");
                result.setText("Login successful");   
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ok.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }else
            {
                Log.w("KASIRIS", "FALSE");
            //  finish();
                result.setText(str);  

            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == ok){
            postLoginData();

        }
           //start new Activity
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you get "Successful Login"?

Comment: This is just not the way of doing it : first do a new thread to make your web request (or use an Handler) and then post a runnable to an handler enabling you to communicate with your view.

Comment: Marcus ... your right I am not receiving a Successful login from Server, but when I try the http from Desktop Browser I can login without problem ... now I don't know why adroid isn't reading my user information from the device.

Comment: AsTeR ... what I want to do is have users login in (have that information saved to server then user proceeds to next activity or application destroy) or register. It may be server side but I don't know why??